# Hide window in Perl/Tk and show again incl. all widgets

Tags: perl, user-interface, show-hide, perltk

I want to hide the mainwindow for a certain amount of time then show it again.
Example:

```
use Tk;

my $mw = new MainWindow;
my $lblMsg = $mw -> Label(-text=>"blabla")-> grid();
my $btnPostpone = $mw -> Button(-text=>"Postpone for (min): ",
              -command =>\&postpone)-> grid();

MainLoop;

sub postpone{
$mw-> withdraw();
sleep(1);
$mw->deiconify();
$mw->raise();
sleep(1);
exit;
}
```

With the above code the main window will reappear but none of the widgets are displayed.
What do I have to do so everything will look exactly the way it did before it was hidden?

Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `$mw->update();` after you `raise()` the main window.

The [Tcl Tk Wiki](http://www2.tcl.tk/1252) explains why in a bit of detail.

Comment: Fixed broken link.